# Any IntelliJ IDEA plugins to search source code for java libs?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I know how to attach source code to a lib, or search source code for maven projects. However, I want to search source code of a lib online within IDEA, for example, `"javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory"`. Is there any plugins to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Give [insight.io](https://www.insight.io) a try, it supports qualified name symbol search:
[image]

And it has code browsing experience close to an IDE.
[image]